# Query working in management studio and not working when run from installer created with wix toolset

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-express, wix3.11

The problem is when I run the setup.msi, RESTORE DATABASE terminate abnormally error code is returned but when I run the query in ssms, it's working fine. Is there any limitation of sqlstring element?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SQLRestore" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SQLRestore" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="CMP_Database_Autoruns" Guid="75FAEA47-E1E3-4A58-9528-4577968EA058" KeyPath="yes">
            <sql:SqlDatabase Id="Database_MyDB" Server="[ComputerName]\EXPRESS2019" Database="Test" CreateOnInstall="no" DropOnUninstall="yes">
                <sql:SqlString Id="SQL_CreateMyTable"
                               SQL="RESTORE DATABASE Test
                               FROM DISK = N'F:\Bak\KK2.bak' WITH FILE = 1, 
                               MOVE N'Test' TO N'F:\DATA\TTest.mdf', 
                               MOVE N'Test_log' TO N'F:\DATA\TTest_log.ldf',
                               NOUNLOAD,
                               REPLACE,
                               STATS = 5;" ContinueOnError="no" ExecuteOnInstall="yes"/>
            </sql:SqlDatabase>
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is a very product specific question.)

Comment: mssql version is 2019 Express

Comment: well, what's the exact error you're getting when restoring? i'm guessing you have some connections against the database, which ssms kills, but your script doesn't. the way to do is to set database in single_user mode with rollback_immediate before restoring with replace

Comment: How many computers will have F:\Bak\ and F:\DATA\ folders available on them?